# Token mismatch error while calling laravel route from mobile

Tags: laravel

I am trying to call route from mobile app, while i am hitting the url it shows token mismatch error, i dont want exclude from VerifyCsrfToken.php, any solution please?

Comment: Is the app passing the token?

Comment: Please extend your question. Add some code example and a little story what you got to do and what do you have

Answer (score 1):

kindly elaborate your question... are using trying an ajax request?

your request type etc.

if you are using ajax post then adding _token to data object might help

e.g. `"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"` to your object

Comment: you should not post comments as answers

Comment: i have added possible answer as well for an ajax request

Answer (score 0):

CSRF Token Mismatch error comes only when you try to post data to a Route, the route is mentioned in *web.php* and you are not passing the CSRF Token Value as hidden parameter with name *_token*

Recommendations:

If it's an API then you can add your API routes in *api.php* instead of *web.php* and the URL will be `example.com/api/<route>`

You can pass the token from the form for that you can user
`{!! csrf_field() !!}` in your blade file or for AJAX request you can directly pass the token value `{{ csrf_token() }}`

Answer (score -2):

I think you are hitting REST API, so sessions are not being maintained. CSRF stores a values in session and in cookie on user browser, when we submit form, they both should match.

you can turn off CSRF from kernal.php

Comment: First of all as you can see in question his don't want to disable it. Second this is a horrible idea to disable CSRF protection